# incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc'

Tags: c++, algorithm

My program is

```
#include <iostream>

char * grabNumber ( char * begin )
{
    // Interpret *begin as the start of a double and add the characters to a
    // string retstr

    char * begincpy = begin;
    int foundDot = 0;
    while ((*begin >= '0' && *begin  <= '9') || *begin == '.')
    {
        if (*begin == '.')
        {
            if (foundDot == 0) foundDot = 1;
            else break;
        }
        ++begin;
    }
    long n = begin - begincpy; // # of characters parsed
    char * retstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 1)); // string to be returned
    for (long k = 0; k < n; ++k) retstr[k] = *begincpy++;
    retstr[n] = '\0';
    return retstr;
}

int main()
{
   char str [] = "abc3.14def";
   std::cout << grabNumber(str+3); // should print "3.14"
   return 0;
}
```

and the errors I'm getting are

> Line 20: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in
>   function 'malloc' Line 21: error: 'for' loop initial declaration used
>   outside C99 mode

corresponding to the 2 lines

```
    char * retstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 1)); // string to be returned
    for (long k = 0; k < n; ++k) retstr[k] = *begincpy++;
```

See: http://codepad.org/c2tNGFEo

Also, is there a way that I can cut down on the redundancy of my algorithm, because it's checking for a `.` twice in each iteration of the `while` loop, and yet I can't think of a cleaner way to handle the fact that I need to stop the loop if we've run into a second `.`

Comment: `std::cout` is illegal in C. Was this meant to be a C++ question?

Comment: On this site it's best to stick to one question per question. Post a separate question about your algorithm's efficiency once you have gotten it running and giving the right output.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I've now got it running and am getting the right output

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are trying to write C++ as you have included `iostream` and used `std::cout`. However the error message shows you are using a C compiler. I also guess that you wrote `gcc myprogram.c`.  To get C++ compilation you either need to write `g++` instead of `gcc`, or rename your file to have a `.cc` extension. (Preferably both).

---

To use `malloc` you need `#include <cstdlib>`.

Also you may need `using namespace std;` or `using std::malloc;` after that; and you will need to cast the value returned by `malloc` because C++ does not implicitly convert from `void *` to other pointer types.

However `malloc` is rarely used in C++ as it does not initialize non-trivial objects properly. Consider changing this code to:

```
char * retstr = new char[n+1];
```

then you won't need any extra includes.

---

But this is still a weak design as you are now relying on the caller to free the memory. In fact your `main` function has a memory leak as it does not free the memory.

In C++ it is better style to have memory managed by a container class that knows about memory management; so the programmer can't make any mistakes. (Incase you are wondering, this usually doesn't introduce any inefficiency and may even speed things up).

A much better approach would be to `#include <string>`, make the function return `std::string`, and change the last five lines of your function to:

```
return { begincpy, begin };
```

or if using a pre-C++11 compiler,

```
return std::string(begincpy, begin);
```

Comment: Good points in case of C++, but since our intrepid programmer is clearly trying to compile the code as C that needs to be remedied first(!). (You can tell by the error message about C-99 mode, which is something GCC will spit out.)

Comment: @user268396 hard to say; it could be that he intended to write C++ and used the wrong compiler

Comment: Yeah, that is what needs fixing: he should invoke the C++ compiler instead of the C one. Otherwise none of your perfectly good C++ fixes is going to fix a thing(!) because the C compiler won't care to know what an iostream or a std::string or an overloaded << operator is.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by observing that you are not writing C, you are writing C++. You should fix your compilation/project settings so you compile your files using the C++ compiler instead of the C compiler. This will fix the compilation error about the `for` loop also, as that is not valid in C before C-99.

Secondly, the first warning is actually due to a missing `include`. In C you would `#include <stdlib.h>` in C++ you'd `#include <cstdlib>` to get the definitions from the C standard library.